# mysql group_concat to JSON in ZF - results repeating escape backslashes

Tags: php, mysql, json, zend-framework, group-concat

Connecting an app to a ZF 1.12 LAMP stack with MySQL 5.6.14 with PHP 5.4.24

I have a long query that is mostly single row results with a couple of multiple row results
hence I'm using a `group_concat` for the multi row results.

I need the results in JSON format - so I'm using the following SQL concat query 
to output JSON format from MySQL directly - using `$select = $this->_db->quoteInto("SELECT...")`

The rest of the query / results are fine, so I'll only list the problem line:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('{name: \"',name,'\", age:\"',age,'\"}') ORDER BY age ASC SEPARATOR '|') AS person_details,
```

When I explode (using my '|' separator) the results I get look like this:

```
"person_details": [
            "{name: \"Fred\", age:\"17\"}",
            "{name: \"James\", age:\"23\"}"
],
```

...with the escape characters repeated in the result...

If I don't include the '\' escape characters the query doesn't work

I've tried :

- the identical query *without backslashes* in phpMyAdmin and it works fine (ie the results come out in correct JSON format without repeating the included '\' escape characters)
- testing both `"$select = $this->_db->select()"` and `"$select = $this->_db->quoteInto("`formats for query in ZF - both give the same result

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use " instead ' ?

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT("{name: \"",name,"\", age:\"",age,"\"}") ORDER BY age ASC SEPARATOR "|") AS person_details,
```

Comment: yes i've tried using double " instead of single ' - it doesn't work - either in phpMyAdmin (where it gives a #1064 error) or ZF (where i get no result).  The fact that the single quotation query works fine (and gives correctly formatted results) in phpMyAdmin tells me that the query structure is OK.  thanks.